# Javascript testing vs remix

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, truffle-test

So what would be the benefit of testing the smart contracts using javascript with truffle instead of remix? I just feel is really tedious. I'm guessing there is a reason, but I don't see it, so should I keep learning to test with js?

Comment: Performance might be one reason if your contracts are complex. A browser is usually sandboxed for security reasons. At the end it is a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

With you js you can do a larger variety of tests.
Especially when you build a project like a Play 2 Earn, you have to test a lot of things.